# Loading a partial part of a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a very large webpage that loads a lot of box's with images inside of them. There could be anywhere from 3-100 box's on a page and each box has a height of 1000px.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    ...
    ..
    .
</div>
```

I don't want the user to have to wait for 10-100 high res images and content to load inside the `.box` so I am trying to figure out the best way to only load what the user can see and keep loading as the user scrolls.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure one of the terms is 'lazy loading images'. Google it, you will get a bunch of results.

Comment: also check infinite scroll :)

Comment: @JoshCrozier would these work even if the images are a `background-image` of a div?

Comment: @bryan The recommendation was to Google the term and see what you find, so perhaps you can find that out yourself?

Answer (score 1):

http://jscroll.com/

Infinite Scrolling seems to be your best option. Websites such as tumblr uses this to have large amounts of content in one page but without the massive loading time. Data is only loaded when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out previously, infinite scrolling seems to be a good option to solve your problem.
Here is a great website with some demos and some code you can look up. The first demo seems to be exactly like your site:

http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the scroll event and then figure out which elements are visible and load the image then